# Error in Json Parsing?

Tags: android, json

I am newbie in android so i am not famalier to all errors here is the error that I am getting  (Unreachable catch block for JSONException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body) in my **catch** clause while json parsing. Can anyone please tell what shall i do.Thanks here my code:

```
if (usernameEditText == null || passwordEditText == null)
{
  Toast.makeText(HelloAndroid.this, "Please enter your username & password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
  // display the username and the password in string format
  try 
  {
    showBusyCursor(true);
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...", "Login in process", true);

    Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Username: " + sUserName + "nPassword: " + sPassword);
    Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to "+address);

    JSONObject json = RestJsonClient.connect(address);
  }
  catch (JSONException e) 
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    showBusyCursor(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting for us to see an excerpt of your code throwing the exception.

Comment: It helps if you (1) post the code, (2) format the code and the error message correctly.  If you need help, read the FAQ.  Please **Edit** your question to properly format the smallest piece of code that shows the error and properly format the error message.  When you're editing, the instructions are on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error means, that 
**1.** either the code in your `try` block never throws an `JSONException`,
**2.** or the `JSONException` is caught before the `catch (JSONException e)` block, so your `try-catch` block might look like:

```
try {
    [...]
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // some code
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    //some other code...
}
```

Here the `catch (Exception e)` block is called before the `JSONException`, and since `JSONException` extends the `Exception` class, it won't be entered ever.

In this case you should change the order of your catch blocks, and will be able to handle the two exception types differently.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to a get better understanding of how to do JSON parsing in android:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Plus provide the log of your error that you are getting and the code you are using. Without error log and code no one cant tell what is wrong.